# Moodle user profile page is loading even after profile owner has logged out. how can we protect authenticated pages after logout?

Tags: moodle

Moodle (v3.7.1) User has logged in and opened his profile page (user/profile.php?id=5560) and logged out. Now, if any one else opens this profile page url in that same chrome browser, it loads and discloses all profile details even though the owner has logged out. even on page reload. it must be loading from browser cache.

cache-control: private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, no-transform

Can you please advice exactly which file or config has to be changed so that any similar authenticate pages are not cached? thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the pages are not cached. So it will always check the current logged-in user capabilities when calling the `profile.php` page.

Do you have made some customizations to Moodle core?

Maybe it would be a better approach to try to reproduce this error on a clean Moodle 3.7.1 installation. If it exists than you should create a Moodle tracker issue. But I don't think that the error is due to a Moodle core bug.

Greets
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Check your site security settings.
Go to *Site administration > Security > Site security settings*
and make sure the following settings are checked:

- Force users to log in for profiles
- Force users to log in to view user pictures